# Proof of injectivity and surjectivity

Tags: real-analysis

I've the following function $k: \Re^{2} \to \Re$ defined by

\begin{equation*}
k(x,y)=x^2+y^2.
\end{equation*}

How I can proceed by proof the his injectivity\surjectivity?

Comment: This is not injective for instance k(x,y)=k(-x,-y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can show that this function is not injective, for instance, take the ordered pairs $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ which is in $\mathscr{R}^2$. We see that $k(-1,-1)=k(1,1)$ but $(-1,-1)\neq(1,1)$.

It also not surjective since we can't find any ordered pairs $(x,y) \in\mathscr{R}^2$ such that $x^2+y^2<0$, and the negative real numbers are in $\mathscr{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not surjective.

If $a<0$, then $k(x,y)\neq a\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R^2}$

Also, it is not injective for $k(x,y)=k(y,x)$ even when $x\neq y$.

For example,

$k(3,4)=25=k(4,3)$ even though $(3,4)\neq(4,3)$

QED.

Comment: How can you see that is not injective?

Comment: $(x,y)\neq(y,x)$ but $k(x,y)=k(y,x)$. Thus, it is not one to one.

Comment: If e.g. $(x,y)=(1,1)$ then $(x,y)=(y,x)$. A fixed counterexample is preferable.

Comment: I mean, not necessarily equal. I'll give a fixed counter example.